# Can number values default to Float64 instead of Int64 in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to convert some code to Polars from Pandas to test the gain in performance. I'm having trouble with Polars import some spreadsheets where multiple columns have mostly 0's except for a few cases. Polars automatically treats them as Int64 due to the number of 0's and I want to avoid having to parse the entire dataset with `infer_schema_length = None`.

Setting every column needed to Float64 is also quite time consuming and I'd prefer to avoid it so if I could get Polars to just use Float64 instead of Int64, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You've got the `infer_schema_length` backwards. Setting it to `None` doesn't make it parse the whole file. If you set it to `None` then it just uses the default which is 100. [See here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html)</strike> Now, setting `infer_schema_length` to None *does* have it scan the whole file.

I don't think there's a way to tell polars to abandon Ints in favor of Floats.

As a work around you could load a small subset of the file and then use that to create a dtypes list that replaces Ints with Floats

```
df=pl.read_csv(filepath, n_rows=5, n_threads=1, sample_size=5)
df=pl.read_csv(filepath, dtypes=[x if not "Int" in str(x) else pl.Float64() for x in df.dtypes])
```

Note: In my opinion, it shouldn't be necessary to specify the `sample_size` parameter so I put in a bug report so in future versions, hopefully, that won't be necessary.

Comment: Wrt "I put in a bug report" adding the issue link for others who run into this in the future: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8677

Comment: Note to others: 'infer_schema_length = None' now does seem to use the full dataframe /file to determine the schema  (it seems to have changed in the same documentation link that Dean MacGregor provided). Polars development moves so fast it's hard to keep up!